# Unable to install Cuda 9.0

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

When trying to install cuda 9 i get the following errors. Im using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-drivers : Depends: nvidia-410 (>= 410.48) but it is not going to be installed
 libcuda1-410 : Depends: nvidia-410 (>= 410.48) but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-410-dev : Depends: nvidia-410 (>= 410.48) but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-opencl-icd-410 : Depends: nvidia-410 (>= 410.48) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I then try to run "apt --fix-broken install" it prompts me to install packets i type yes but that doesnt work and i get the following error.

```
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-410_410.48-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-410 (410.48-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-410_410.48-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/sbin/create-uvm-dev-node', which is also in package nvidia-kernel-common-390 390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-410_410.48-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm not sure what I have to do. Any help would be much appreciated.
using a gtx 1050ti and verified it was installed using nvidia-smi.

Steps I have taken:

--fix-broken (didnt work as described above)

--fix-policy (install more packages but had the same error as above for the nvidia drive)

rebooted (now for some reason my nvidia driver is uninstalled and cant reinstall it)

If theres anyway to remove all packages i'd love to know i've tried everything and nothing works

I am following the instructions found here: https://github.com/markjay4k/Install-Tensorflow-on-Ubuntu-17.10-/blob/master/Tensorflow%20Install%20instructions.ipynb

I was able to reinstall the correct nvidia drivers by using sudo apt-get purge nvidia* then reinstalling as per the instructions. Im still not sure what i should do to install cuda should i follow the instructions again and hope it doesnt happen again?

Comment: always include mention of which version of ubuntu ... especially on graphics driver questions

Comment: Can you add the link to what instructions you are following to install CUDA 9?  Thank you!

Comment: Hmmmm, the files that it is missing come from this repo here http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/ which is used for 16.04 and not 18.04.  I am not in a place to test things out, but this installation could be extremely complicated to get working.

Comment: I missed your part about reinstalling CUDA.  I would say yes to reinstalling and crossing your fingers that it doesn't happen again.  I guess you could post comments to the NVIDIA developers site requesting that they package CUDA 9.x with the NVIDIA 410 drivers for the CUDA repositories.